# Maintaining RF when node fails

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, database-replication

Does Cassandra maintains RF when a node goes down. For e.g. if number of nodes is 5 and RF is 2 then when a single node goes down, does the remaining replica copies it's data to some other node to maintain the RF of 2?

In the [Datastax's documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archDataDistributeVnodesUsing.html), it's mentioned that "`If a node fails, the load is spread evenly across other nodes in the cluster".` Does this mean that migration of data happens when a node goes down? Is this a feature available only in Datastax's Cassandra and not Apache Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

No, instead a "hint" will be stored in the coordinator node and will get eventually written to the node which owns the token range when the node comes back up - the write will succeed depending on your consistency level. So in the above example the write will succeed if you are writing with consistency level as ONE.

If the node is down only for short period - the node will receive the data back from hints from other nodes when it comes back. But if you decommission a node, then the data gets replicated to other nodes and the other nodes will have the new token ranges (same case when a node is added to the cluster as well).

Over time the data in one replica can become inconsistent with others and the repair process helps Cassandra in fixing them - https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesTOC.html

This is applicable in Apache Cassandra as well.

Comment: So the data migration takes place only after the node is decommissioned. But then that statement in the Datastax's documentation seems incorrect, doesn't it?

Comment: Well your snippet is from the vnode context and it full wording says: "Rebalancing a cluster is automatically accomplished when adding or removing nodes. When a node joins the cluster, it assumes responsibility for an even portion of data from the other nodes in the cluster. If a node fails, the load is spread evenly across other nodes in the cluster." Maybe it was best stated like: "...If a node fails and is removed, the load..."

Comment: It is not incorrect - its only saying the load is spread across other nodes and which is always true by design. When one node is down its not like one other node takes the responsibility but rather all the other nodes will share the load depending who is the coordinator node on each query.

Comment: and yes as Steffen mentioned - it would be more accurate if they say like a node is failed and removed in the context.

Comment: Mpadikka is also right in the distinction between 'load' and 'data' but I'm thinking talk of 'load' in this context is a bad mix :) ... but the doc is properly written by humans